# How to increase UITableView Height Dynamically When number of cell is increased using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[image]

I am new to iOS. I have implemented a table view which is populated with array values successfully, but I'm not satisfied with the result. When I scroll my table view the top values are hiding.

Here is my problem: based on the cell height the table view height should also get increased dynamically in `UITableview`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: why you want to increase your table height, it is kind of scrollView. you can render as many rows in it, this will scroll till end. And if you tries to show all rows in one screen then it is difficult if total rows size more than screen height.

Comment: As from image, have you added Textfields and Done Button in TableView?

Comment: No,I have created a tableview in bottom and of my viewcontroller

Comment: when I scroll the tableview the top values are getting hide,The solution for that is to increase tableview height, but I don't know how to do??

Comment: You can increase size from Storyboard or Xib where you added TableView. If that table view height increased from your device bottom, then that height is of no use, because your content will render in TableView and cell object will hide.

Comment: TableView starts scroll when its height ends. so if you increase size below your device bottom, then that cell will not visible. So good idea is keep your table height equal to your view bottom.

Comment: My need is viewcontroller inside I have tableview height is 191,my cell height is 80,when cell count is increase my tableview height also get increased dynamically...this what I asking??

Comment: For this you need to set constraint to TableView and programmatically increase height constraint of TableView.

Answer (score 0):

For UITableViewCell dynamic height you can use following `delegate` by return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 300; //give maximum heigh you want
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

and to increase tableview height based on content size use the below line of code

```
YOUR_TABLE_VIEW_HEIGHT_CONSTRAINT.constant = [YOUR_TABLE_VIEW contentSize].height;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: when I run I got this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'table view row height must not be negative - provided height for index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) is -1.000000'

Comment: answer updated check it once and give some top and bottom constraint of elements in cell don't give 0 constant @ShubamGupta

Comment: this also not working for me, My need is viewcontroller inside I have tableview height is 191,my cell height is 80,when cell count is increase my tableview height also get increased dynamically...this what I asking??

Comment: answer update for increase tableview height based on content size after reloading table view get content height and set to constraint @ShubamGupta